# Get userAgentData on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-agent

How can I use `userAgentData` on server(Nodejs)? In express i am trying to use new JS api:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgentData

I tried this
`

```
console.log(global.navigator)
```

But this is printing `undefined`.

I am also on https.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to access that field as follows on client side:

`window.navigator.userAgentData`

Note:
You cannot access `userAgentData` from the server. You would have to access the data in the frontend and pass it to your server through the request body.